# How To Change stylesheet by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've try's to get element and change the style by content: if element content is `English` then CSS should be `ltr.css` `else if` element content is `Persian` the css should be 'rtl.css'
here is what i have

```js
    addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        
        var lang = document.getElementById('languageChooser').innerHTML;

        if(lang == 'Persian'){
            document.querySelector('#style1').setAttribute('href', 'rtl.css');;
        } else if (lang == 'English') {
            document.querySelector('#style1').setAttribute('href', 'ltr.css');;
        }
    })
```

```html
  <a href="" id="languageChooser">Persian</a>
  <link id="style1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ltr.css" />
```

this is the whole application

Comment: and does this not work? what is the problem you're having?

Comment: nope, even before </body>

Comment: Typo: You forgot the `if` after the `else` and before your second condition.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can definitely swap the css file. Do this on **button click**.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link id="style1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ltr.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="languageChooser">Persian</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#languageChooser").click(function() {
        var lang = document.getElementById('languageChooser').innerHTML;
        var selector = $('link[href*="ltr.css"]');
        if (lang == 'Persian') {
            selector.replaceWith('<link href="rtl.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">');
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i can't do this with button. language selector isn't accessible. I can only use content of #languageChooser

Comment: @AghaFree i edited my answer, check it again please!

Comment: I added your solution, but no results

Comment: @AghaFree jan the error is because you didnt add jquery.

Comment: may i have your full solution?

Comment: @AghaFree i pasted all detailed code. and it works fine

Comment: sajad, i can't use click to change the language. the language most defined from id content. like this: `<div id="languageChooser">Persian</div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201446/discussion-between-sajad-haibat-and-aghafree).

Answer (score -1):

You just have to change attribute of link element like this

```
document.querySelector('link').setAttribute('href', 'ltr.css');
```

**EDIT**

Make sure that your script is executed after loading the document content.
(add `script` tag at the end of the html file, or use `defer` script attribute, or use `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: that would get the first link in the document, you should use `style1` id here instead.

Comment: having said that, that is essentially the same thing OP has already.. so, the question is why doesn't it work?  and it's probably because the document isn't going to fetch the resource after it's done loading.

Comment: ye, you can use `style1` instead of `link`. It was just an example.
Did you add `<script>`at the end of your html file? This is one of the solutions, to run script if document is loaded. You can also use `DOMContentLoaded` event, or `defer` script's attribute.

Comment: i'm not pro javascript coder. so think simply. maybe i missed something

Comment: then try to use one of my ideas, check if you have an access to element in script. If you haven't, then the probem is that you run your script before DOM is loaded and my solution works

Comment: @wglugla ! can you write the right code?(all of it)

Comment: @AghaFree man, just try to `console.log(el)`. If it'll be `undefined` then you'll know that you have to do one of the possibilites:
- make sure that `<script>` tag is added at the end of file (before `</body>`)
- add `defer` to script (like this: `<script src="..." defer></script`), then your script will be executed after DOM load
- wrap your operations in `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {...})`

Comment: @wglugla . i changed the question with your suggestion. is that the right solution?

Comment: @AghaFree `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ..)` and it should be great, is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201445/discussion-between-aghafree-and-wglugla).

Answer (score -1):

```
let el = document.querySeletor("#style1");

el.setAttribute("href", (lang == "Persian")? "rtl.css" : "ltr.css");
```

If I understood correctly you can automatically change style file, by language.